# Asking about smartcard-related question

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should I ask about smartcard/rfid-card related question?

What I want to ask is

> "Is RFID card UID always unique?"

Comment: Maybe [security.SE]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) seems the best choice, since it has already been asked there and seems to be well received:

[Passive RFID Tag: Unique Identifiers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/16353)

Also, a partial answer is given on SO: [Can the UID on a RFID chip be overriden?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15478961/993547), although I wouldn't expect the question you ask to be on-topic there:

> Non-unique: the set of 32-bit UID is nearly exhausted. Manufacturers are starting to re-use older unique IDs. A remaining range of 32-bit IDs has been designated as non-unique in the ISO 14443 standard and cannot be relied upon as being unique.

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).  Perhaps [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) might also help. I don't think there's anywhere else for it.

Comment: [security.se], yes, assuming that the question is about the use of a RFID as part of some security architecture. [crypto.se], no, unless the question was about the details of some implementation that is supposed to guarantee uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

A friendly piece of advice: that is not likely to be a good question anywhere, in its current form.  A one-sentence question is rarely a good one.   No matter where you ask, make sure to flesh out the question.  Tell us what research you've done, what your thoughts are, what the context/motivation is.

Information Security.SE is only relevant if there is an adversary somewhere (e.g., if you're worried about an adversary who might try to create two cards with the same UID) -- but in that case make sure to read the help page there, and include information on your threat model.

This is not suitable for Cryptography.SE.